# How to copy class attributes without instantiation

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to copy class attributes from one class to another

```
d = {1:'one', 2:'two'}
class X(object):
    a = 1
    b = 2
```

I need to define class Y such that the following is true:
`assert Y.a =='one' and Y.b=='two'`

One way to achieve this is as follows:

```
attrDict = {attr:d[getattr(X,attr)] for attr in dir(X) if isinstance(getattr(X,attr), int)}
# attrDict is {'a':'one', 'b':'two'}

class Y(X):
    def __init__(self):
        self.copyOver()

    @classmethod
    def copyOver(klass):
        [setattr(klass, k,v) for k,v in attrDict.iteritems()]

y = Y()  # Y.a = 1 unless this runs
assert Y.a == 'one' and Y.b == 'two'
```

However, instantiation can be expensive in a real application: Would it be possible to achieve this without?

In other words, ***what built-in do I use to update class attributes without requiring instantiation of an object of it***?

```
class Y(X):
    #TODO: setattr all key value pairs in attrDict on the class Y, not on instances of it.
    #TODO: Do it without requiring to instantiate an object of class Y
```

Comment: Please don’t abuse list comprehensions for side-effects =( Anyway, you can just call `Y.copyOver()` right after defining `Y` instead of doing it in `__init__`. Or even make that a completely separate function since it doesn’t need to be a classmethod: `copy_over(Y, attrDict)`

Comment: @Ryan, Sure - list comprehension used only to concisely demonstrate one solution. I agree with `Y.copyOver()`. However, how do I ensure that everyone using Y would run Y.copyOver() ? How to force it?

Comment: You can use metaclasses for that, since they’re inherited, but what are you really trying to accomplish with this? What overall look?

Comment: That is what I was thinking - do you have an example? Y is a popular class. X has been recently moved out for separation of concerns. I need to continue supporting existing use cases of Y.a and Y.b instead of asking everyone to switch to using X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what you have but without creating the dictionary in between:

```
In [120]: d = {1:'one', 2:'two'}
     ...: class X(object):
     ...:     a = 1
     ...:     b = 2
     ...:

In [121]: class Y(X):
     ...:     @classmethod
     ...:     def change_me(cls):
     ...:         for k, v in X.__dict__.items():
     ...:             if v in d:
     ...:                 setattr(cls, k, d[v])
     ...:

In [122]: Y.a
Out[122]: 1

In [123]: Y.change_me()

In [124]: Y.a
Out[124]: 'one'

In [125]: X.a
Out[125]: 1
```

Here is a version using *metaclasses*, that addresses your concern with having to explicitly run a *classmethod* (assuming python3):

```
In [145]: d = {1:'one', 2:'two'}
     ...: class X(object):
     ...:     a = 1
     ...:     b = 2
     ...:
     ...:

In [146]: class ChangeOnCreation(type):
     ...:     def __init__(cls, name, bases, attr_dict):
     ...:         super().__init__(name, bases, attr_dict)
     ...:         for subs in bases:
     ...:             for k, v in subs.__dict__.items():
     ...:                 if v in d:
     ...:                     setattr(cls, k, d[v])
     ...:

In [147]: class Y(X, metaclass=ChangeOnCreation):
     ...:     pass
     ...:

In [148]: Y.a
Out[148]: 'one'

In [149]: X.a
Out[149]: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this. A similar solution has already been mentioned in a comment by @Ryan. The requirement however is to force anyone and everyone accessing `Y.a` or `Y.b` to transparently have run it and not just within the module that this resides in. Cannot force all use cases of `Y.a` to run `Y.change_me()` prior to use.

Comment: Excellent. That works and I cannot see any side effects. Accepted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping you from assigning the values directly on your type (class)? e.g.:

```
class X(object):
    a = 1
    b = 2

d = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}

class Y(X): pass

for k in dir(Y):
    val = getattr(Y, k)
    try:
        if val in d:
            setattr(Y, k, d[val])
    except TypeError:
        pass  # ignore the types that cannot be in our `d`

assert Y.a == "one" and Y.b == "two"
```